# Is there a way to get the JOptionPane drop down menu to output numbers for the selected choice?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Ok my phrasing might be kind of confusing but let me explain.

```
String[] choices = { "John", "Bob", "Jenny"};
String input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose who you want to trade with",
    "", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, choices,choices[1]);
    System.out.println(input);
```

I got this code for a basic drop down menu off some java tutorial website. What happens is that the output is just the the names instead of something like a JOptionPane I found on the internet for buttons where the output is numbers:

```
Object[] options = {"Clothes", "Food", "Repair equipment", "Leave the shop"};
    int Store = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "WELCOME TO THE GENERAL GOODS STORE, WHAT WOULD YOU LIKE\n                                                 you have $" + money, "Welcome",
            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
            null, options, options[0]);
```

It makes it really hard to make if statements responding to the choice the user makes. And just so nobody says to just do a input.equals("John") sort of thing, the names are going to be randomized and have different phrases before them which would make that harder to do. Ok hopefully that made some sense and wasn't just a confusing mess. I can clarify certain points if need be.

Answer (score 0):

You can add any component to a JOptionPane, so you could add a JPanel that contains:

1. A Jlabel with a message
2. The JComboBox

The basic code is:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
panel.add(new JLabel("Choose who you want to trade with"), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
panel.add(comboBox, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
    frame, // use your JFrame here
    panel, 
    "Use a Panel",
    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

if(result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
{
    int index = comboBox.getSelectedIndex();
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Canceled");
}
```